# How can I get data when I convet a cold flow to hot flow using shareIn in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I know that the Flow is cold, I can use `collect` to get every data just like Code A.

If I convert a Flow to hot flow using `shareIn` just like Code B, how can I get every data in a hot flow?

**CodeA**

```
val simple: Flow<Int> = flow { 
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100) 
        emit(i) 
    }
}


class LatestNewsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
               simple.collect{ i- > print(i)}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
val hotSimple:  SharedFlow<Int> = flow { 
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100) 
        emit(i) 
    }
}.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), replay = 1)


class LatestNewsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
               //I want to print every data in hotSimple.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to guarantee it is to give `shareIn` a replay value that is at least as big as the number of values the source flow will produce. This wouldn’t be a practical solution in most cases because you don’t always know how many values the upstream flow will produce, or it might be infinite. Also, every item in the replay is kept in memory, so memory use might be a concern. It is only the emitted values that are replayed, so for new subscribers the side effects and delays will not be replayed along with the emitted values.

The whole point of using a SharedFlow is so it doesn’t have to restart for new subscribers. So typically you would not use a SharedFlow for something where you want every subscriber to receive every value from the beginning.